# Sprites not moving in sync... look jittery/shakey

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I've got 2 sprites added to the stage, one holding bitmapdata (the background/land) and the other holding movieclips (characters), creating a topdown view of the world. As the player moves around this world the second movieclip seems to move in a shakey way, not completely in sync with the background clip. I've noticed that when I set the game quality to medium this shakiness disappears... unfortunately I cant just set one sprite to its own quality, right?

Is there any way to solve this problem? To my novice eyes it seems like the background is moving smoothly but the top sprite is moving pixel by pixel or something.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: Probably going to have to show some code.

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem:

```
Bitmap.pixelSnapping = false;
```

Set this property on whichever object ( the background or characters ) is a bitmap.